# Best practice on file structure - using Request module (Node.js + Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've just installed Request module in my express + node.js project and I would like to know in which folder I should place my custom js file that will contain the following code that basically executing Request module.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

This is just an example code and I will have my own, possibly mode code than this so I'm assuming putting this in odd place inside app.js is not considered best practice.

I'm also not sure if node_module folder is the right place for this executing purpose.

Comment: Advice on app structure depends entirely on the app's functionality, its size and continued development. I don't see how we'd be able to answer this. My *hunch* is that you should keep it in `app.js` until you feel that refactoring it into another file may make development easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, it's difficult for the SO community to dictate how you structure your application without knowing a lot more about what the application does.

However, you have asked if `node_modules` would be a good place to execute your application code...

The answer to that is a resounding 'no'. The `node_modules` folder is specifically for modules that are used by the application, not the application itself.

A typical node application looks like this:

```
├── app.js
├── package.json
├── node_modules
   ├── module1
   ├── module2
   ├── etc...
```

Generally, your application would be written in `app.js`, and your external modules will be stored in `node_modules` by the [Node Package Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/) when executing the `npm install` command on the command line. NPM installs the packages that are listed in the `package.json` file. It would be bad practise to store application code in `node_modules` because this folder is often assumed to be re-buildable through NPM, and is usually removed by various applications/developers to make your application more transportable.

If you want to split your code into smaller chunks, then you can require specific files instead of known-modules.

Here's an example:

**folder structure**

```
├── app.js
├── lib
   ├── my-local-module.js
├── package.json
├── node_modules
```

**lib/my-local-module.js**

```
module.exports = function() {

  console.log('Hello World!');

}
```

**app.js**

```
var myLocalModule = require('./lib/my-local-module.js');

myLocalModule(); // Hello World!
```

Every program needs to start somewhere. In this case, you would bootstrap this application by running `node app.js` on the command line. That code, in turn, would localise your `my-local-module.js` file through the `require` statement.

As I said before; my advice would be to keep your code inside one file until you feel your codebase has gotten big enough to warrant refactoring and delegating logic to other files.

Comment: Thanks, it cleared up my doubts. My app only runs with `npm start`, I hope this won't affect localisation of my custom module?

Comment: @SeongLee So long as your `package.json` contains a `start` property in the `scripts` object, you should be fine. Something like: `"start": "node app.js"`.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably a newbie question but how can I return the result of my module and assign to a variable in app.js? Calling `myLocalModule();` won't allow me to use returned JSON data in my case.

Comment: @SeongLee Whatever you assign to `module.exports` in the module file  will be returned from the `require` method call in your main application. So instead of assigning a `function` to `module.exports`, you could instead assign any valid JavaScript data type (objects, arrays, string numbers etc).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this separate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844704/how-to-assign-return-data-object-so-it-can-be-rendered-in-view-node-js