# How to assign return data object so it can be rendered in view (node.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following code and I'm basically making a request to my api to retrieve JSON data and exporting this custom module.

The problem is that with `var data = require('./lib/data.js');` alone, data doesn't really have the data I expected to have.

If it was a physical JSON file sitting in the project, I could do `var data = require('./data.json');` but I don't work with this kind of static data.

What's wrong here?

**data.js** (my custom module to get JSON data)

```
module.exports = function() {

    var request = require("request")
    var url = "http://sheetsu.com/apis/94dc0db4"

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    })

}
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var data = require('./lib/data.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Express' 
    data: data
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider here:

1. Your request to the server is Asynchronous
2. You're not actually returning the data to the `module.exports`
3. Some basic syntax errors in your code

Try this:

**data.js**

```
module.exports = function(callback) {

    var request = require("request")
    var url = "http://sheetsu.com/apis/94dc0db4"

    request({ url: url, json: true }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            callback( body );
        }
    });
}
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var data = require('./lib/data.js');

data( function(data) {

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: data });

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In a bit more detail; the request to get your JSON data will not be synchronous. That means that it can take any amount of time to respond back with the data, so it allows your program to finish its current thread. This means that when your `index.js` file is receiving the `data.js` module, the data may not have arrived yet. You can read more about asynchronous vs synchronous [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean).

How do we get around this problem? We pass the method a `callback` function to execute when it is finished.

When we execute the module...

```
data( function(data) { ...
```

...We're passing it a function to run when it receives the data from the server. If there is no error from the server and the `statusCode` is OK...

```
if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) { ...
```

... Then we *call* the `callback` function that was passed, passing the `body` (or data, if you like) as an argument...

```
callback( body );
```

...We can then use this in our `index.js`...

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: data });
```

Comment: My app crashes complaining syntax error on ` router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {`

Comment: @SeongLee apologies, I forgot a character. Have updated answer.

Comment: Not sure what typo it was. my app still crashes.

Comment: ..../routes/index.js:12
    data: data
    ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @SeongLee What is on line 12 for you? Are you sure you're requiring the `data.js` file as I have written it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90902/discussion-between-shennan-and-seong-lee).